# Esper convert result to java.util.Map

Tags: esper

I am new to Esper, and a created a small program that feeds Esper events in the form of Map.

I have added a listener, and everything works as expected, however, when doing complex queries like count(*) over a time windows, I struggle to get the result back as a java.util.Map. How can I, regardless of query result, get the results as standard Map for further processing?

```
private class EsperUpdateListener implements UpdateListener {
    public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents) {
        System.out.println("Found new event!");
        if(newEvents != null) {
            System.out.println("newEvents (" + newEvents.length + "):");
            for (EventBean e : newEvents) {
                System.out.println("  " + e.toString() + "(" + e.getEventType().getName() + ")");
                System.out.println("    " + e.getUnderlying().toString());

                for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : e.getUnderlying().getEntrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String val = (String)entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println("    " + key + ": " + val);
                }
            }
        }
        if(oldEvents != null) {
            System.out.println("oldEvents:");
            for (EventBean e : oldEvents) {
                System.out.println("  " + e.toString() + "(" + e.getEventType().getName() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the code above, but it complains that getUnderlying returns an Object, not a map. I tried casting, which kinda sorta works, but not without warnings:

warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast

```
Map<String,Object> emap = (Map<String,Object>)e.getUnderlying();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register an UpdateListener, it receives EventBean instances. The "eventBean.getUnderlying()" returns the representation object and in this case a Map.

Comment: It returns Object. When is it safe to assume that this is in fact a Map? The reason why I ask is that when I explicitly cast it to a map, the compiler complaints that "warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast".

Comment: Would checking the instanceof the underlying bean remove this error?

Comment: Yes, there is no warning if you do a proper `instanceof` check of the underlying object like the following: `if (eventBean.getUnderlying() instanceof HashMap<?, ?>) // process data`

Answer (score 0):

You register the event type like this

```
    Map<String, Object> log = new HashMap<>();
    log.put("referer", String.class);
    log.put("request", String.class);
    log.put("logtype", String.class);
    log.put("user_agent", String.class);
    log.put("@cid", String.class);
    log.put("http_version", String.class);
    log.put("user_agent_type", String.class);
    log.put("status", int.class);
    log.put("@timestamp", String.class);
    log.put("server_ip", String.class);
    log.put("client_ip", String.class);
    log.put("method", String.class);
    log.put("write_bytes", int.class);
    log.put("read_bytes", int.class);


    //register
    epServiceProvider.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addEventType("LogType", log);
```

In the UpdateListener use event.getUnderlying() and you will get a Map.